# Why doesn't Silverlight provide IME support?

Tags: silverlight, cjk, ime, windowless

In Silverlight (until version 4), if you set the property `windowless` of the sl plugin to `true`, you can't get any IME support in a textbox.
Does anyone know why? is it a security concern or something else?

Answer (score 2):

I believe this a browser restriction not a SL one, same problem for flash with wmode =transparent. Since windowless allows html to be displayed over the SL object, you may as a workaround float an iframe containing a html input box over your SL input box and on enter key press event on your html  inputbox, call a SL function to take the text result.

Answer (score 0):

This is something intended by microsoft.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838156(VS.95).aspx

Comment: hi, joseph, this does not answer my question. i know that this is by design. but i just wonder why.